# bash loop to change permissions

Tags: bash

I'm trying to change all the permissions for the files in my ~/Documents folder and I thought the following little loop would work, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me? Here's the loop:

```
files=~/Documents/*
for $file in $files {
   chmod 755 $file }
```

I'm trying to write this directly into the bash command line gives me the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `chmod'
```

thanks for your help/advice

Comment: That's not bash syntax. Either match your shell to the syntax you have decided to use (tcsh ?) or match the syntax of your program to the shell (you'll find plenty of bash-scripting tutorials).

Comment: Why are you making all your documents executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop should be :

```
for file in $files
do
   test -f "$file" && chmod 755 "$file"
done
```

Please note that you are relying on [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) when you say `files=~/Documents/*` which will include the directories under `~/Documents` as well, thus using the loop will change permissions of the directories as well. You can add a simple test to make sure that you update only the permission of files. Also please note that globbing can be turned off with `set -f` in which case `files` will have  value of just `<HOME_DIR>/*` which maynot be a filename; which also will not serve your purpose.

**More importantly, as pointed by [ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486249/bash-loop-to-change-permissions/11486272#comment15170500_11486272) it is *not a good idea* to rely on [globbing](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/globbing). When you make use of globbing the filenames with hypens can have undefined behaviour & filenames with semi-colons can cause security vulnerabilities.** Apart for security vulnerabilities associated with globbing there are [some](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) [common](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#cp_.24file_.24target) [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#Filenames_with_leading_dashes) associated with it as well. Please take a look at the [answer provided by ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486763/925381) which highlights some of risks involved with your current operations.

You could use `find` as well (This will recursive set for all the files):
`find ~/Documents/ -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
For setting permissions only for the files under `~/Documents/` you can make use of `-maxdepth` option as such:
`find ~/Documents/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works great -- except that I've learned that what I've written doesn't work for filenames with spaces. Is there a way to escape spaces in bash? something like `escape($file)` before running `chmod 755 $file`?

Comment: @jeff - You need to quote "$file" to prevent word splitting. Your variable expansions should always be quoted, but quoting "$files" in this case wouldn't work since that is when the glob is actually expanding.

Comment: @Jeff: You could make use of the quotes. I have updated the response

Comment: why just use sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Documents/?

Comment: @GTSouza: That will change the permissions of the directories as well, OP wants to update only the files

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for failing to point out that the OP shouldn't rely on fileglobbing in variable assignment.  A filename beginning with a hyphen could cause unpredictable behaviour.  A filename with a semicolon in it could be a security vulnerability.

Comment: If the filenames have spaces, quoting `$file` won't help because `$files` is already being split on spaces.  You'd need to either use an array: `files=(~/Documents/*); for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...` or just skip storing the list at all: `for file in ~/Documents/*; do ...`

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I don't think that it being word-split on iteration here, since the glob is actually not expanded until in the for loop, so its essentially the same as `for file in ~/Documents/*`, although it definitely isn't the approach I would have taken.

Comment: @jordanm: Oops, you're right; it substitutes `~` with the actual home path before assigning it to `files`, but doesn't expand the glob until it's used.  I withdraw the objection (unless there's a space in your home path...)

Comment: @ghoti: Wow! Thanks a ton for that info! I was not aware of semi-colon security issue. I will update my response to mention globbing. If possible can you please provide some reference for these pitfalls pertaining to globbing?

Comment: @ghoti: And for hypen issue do you think `chmod -- 755 "$file"` will be able to fix the problem? I am trying to see this behaviour with files with hypens on bash 4.2.24 on Ubuntu 12.04, but the files seem to work normally. Is there any particular file name? I tried the options of chmod as filenames as well

Answer (score 5):

There are risks in making your documents executable.  I recommend against it unless you know 
exactly what you're doing.

I'm going to take a wild guess that you don't *really* want to make all your Documents folder executable, and what you're really trying to do is standardize on user-writable everyone-else-readable permission for everything in that folder.

Note that (as someone mentioned in another answer) the `chmod` command has its own "recursive" option, `-R`.  *Note also* that you can use "symbolic" permissions with chmod, you're not stuck with octal-only.  So:

```
chmod -R go+r-wx ~/Documents/
```

will add Read and remove Write and eXecute functions from everything in and under `~/Documents/`.

Note that this will make *subdirectories* readable, but will not provide access to the files within them (because that's what the executable bit on a directory does).  So you may want to use TWO commands:

```
find ~/Documents/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ~/Documents/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

The first line only runs `chmod` on directories, making them both readable and accessible.  The second line affects only your files, making them readable by the world.

Comment: You can also use the symbolic permission `go=rX` to set execute on directories but not files (except for files that already have execute permissions, where it assumes the execute is intentional and keeps it...)

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  I always forget about that one.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
find . -exec chmod 755 {} +\;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 755 {} +\;
```

Comment: `-type f` might be needed for OP's query

Comment: He also doesn't indicate if he wants it to be recursive

Comment: i do want to be recursive -- what should I add? `chmod 755 -r $file`?

Comment: @jordan, i assumed `all` meant `all`, hence recursive.

Comment: @jeff, no, it's already set to be recursive. i'll put one more example per cowards suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
chmod -R 755 ~/Documents
```

Comment: well that seems quite simple. However, I think the -R should come before the 755. It didn't work when I did in the order you currently have listed.

Comment: It works either way with coreutils's `chmod`, but I'll change it to be more compatible.

Comment: That makes all his documents executable.

Comment: @Graham: 755 is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Thor - No, 755 was merely in his example. What he asked for was help and advice.